# SImple Inverted Index

Tags: python, strings, file

This is a simple inverted index I made.

The goal is to:

- Read set of text files from a directory, `docs`
- Tokenize them
- Normalize the tokens by removing punctuation and lowercasing them
- create an index of words to doc name, count of docs that that word appears in

Everything works as expected.  I'm just curious what improvements there are to make.

```py
import os
import re
import fileinput


punctuation_regex = r"[^\w\s]"


def normalize_tokens(tokens):
    """Remove all non-alphanumeric characters and convert to lower case"""
    tokens = [re.sub(punctuation_regex, "", str.lower()) for str in tokens]
    return tokens
    

def tokenize_input(input):
    """Split string on whitespace and return unique tokens"""
    tokens = normalize_tokens(input.split())
    return set(tokens)


def read_docs():
    """Read files in docs directory and return map of filename -> tokens in file"""
    docs_to_tokens = {}
    for filename in os.listdir("docs"):
        with open(os.path.join("docs", filename), 'r') as f:
            docs_to_tokens[filename] = tokenize_input(f.read())
    return docs_to_tokens


def make_index():
    """Make inverted index of token -> docs containing token, number of docs containing token"""
    index = {}
    docs = read_docs()
    for doc in docs:
        for str in docs[doc]:
            if not str in index:
                index[str] = {}
                index[str]['count'] = 0
                index[str]['docs'] = []
            index[str]['count'] += 1
            index[str]['docs'].append(doc)
    return index


def query_index(key, index):
    """Return docs that contain key"""
    if key not in index:
        return None
    return index[key]['docs']


def main():
    index = make_index()
    for line in fileinput.input():
        print(query_index(line.rstrip(), index))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice, readable code, and well laid out.

I don't like the hardcoded pathname in `read_docs()` - surely that should be an argument?

Similarly, I would pass the result of `read_docs()` as argument to `make_index()` so it can be tested separately.

Here, we have dicts that we access by exactly two fixed keys:

> ```
>         if not str in index:
>             index[str] = {}
>             index[str]['count'] = 0
>             index[str]['docs'] = []
>         index[str]['count'] += 1
>         index[str]['docs'].append(doc)
> ```

Perhaps we should be using a (named) tuple instead of a dict?  And perhaps `index` should be a `defaultdict`, so we don't need the `str in index` test?

Perhaps `normalize_tokens()` should return a set, rather than creating a list which we then deduplicate in `tokenize_input()`?  Alternatively, make it a generator, which also avoids constructing the list.

Comment: Great suggestions!  Thank you so much!  Will make these changes